# Loss of Multi-Output Model in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a multi-output model in PyTorch when I train them using the same loss and then to backpropagate I combine the loss of both the output but when one output loss decreases others increase and so on. How can I fix the problem?

```py
def forward(self, x):
    #neural network arch. forward pass
    x = dense1(x)
    x1 = dense2(x)
    x2 = dense2(x)
    x1 = F.log_softmax(x1) 
    x2 = F.log_softmax(x2)
    return x1, x2

out1, out2 = model(data)
loss1 = NLLL(out1, target1)
loss2 = NLLL(out2, target2)
loss = loss1 + loss2
loss.backward()
```

When loss1 decrease loss2 increase and when loss2 decrease loss1 increase how can I fix the issue.
Can any other operator other than '+' be used to combine the loss or should I put weights to the different loss?

Comment: Why do you believe this is not a reasonable behavior? Try decreasing the step size.

Comment: I tried that too but it does not help. I made the same model in keras and there both loss decrease simultaneously.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here? Why do you compute the same output twice and compare it with different targets?

Comment: I was trying to predict the prices and amount by the same neural network. That's the reason I was using x which comes from previous layers and then it passes to the log_softmax function.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing everything correctly? You also need to zero the gradients using `optimizer.zero_grad()` and then `optimizer.step()`, but you don't show your full code here. So do check that.

Comment: Can you provide the code with some dummy training data, which still reproduces the problem? This part about applying the same loss function to the same output and different target still confuses me a lot. I would understand if loss functions were different (i.e. taking different parts of the output), but it's not the case.

Comment: @akshayk07 yes I have done all the mentioned steps correctly

Comment: You ask 'Can any other operator other than `+` be used to combine the loss?', so you could use `torch.add` function. But I don't think it will cause any difference since I have seen plenty of code which uses `+` like you have used.

Comment: @akshayk07 I meant by using other function like x=(x1^2+x2^2)^1/2 or other functions to combine the loss.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? What was a solution?

Answer (score -1):

If you have two different loss functions, and you finish the `forwards` for both of them separately, it is smart to do

```
(loss1 + loss2).backward()
```

This is computationally efficient.

What you should achieve is to make your model learn, how to minimize the loss.
Some code from your example is absent, but you should have the `nn.Module`, probable your custom module with parameters inside that should learn to lower to loss.

I liked your approach summing the `loss = loss1 + loss2`.

Comment: how is (loss1+loss2).backward() is different then loss.backward()